# How Can I Tell Which Inherited Class This Belongs To?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

I am working with multiple classes that inherit from a class called Creature. I have an array of Creature objects that I am looping through to determine which out of the array are of the subclass Animal. I tried `instanceOf`, but I was getting a error saying I was declaring it as a variable. Here is what my method looks like:

```
 public void notifyStateChange() {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Class c = creatures[i].getClass();
            if (c.getName().equals("Animal")) {
                System.out.println("Animal type here");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The syntax is `if (creatures[i] instanceof Animal)`

Comment: But if your code needs something like this, it suggests that it might perhaps be better designed since significant use of `instanceof` is an "anti-pattern", a design that suggests broken code.

Comment: With instanceOf I get the error...
Variable declaration not allowed here;
Incompatible types: Creature cannot be converted to boolean

Comment: just override a method in inherited classes, and invoke the methods from reference

Comment: Something's not right here. Post your code with your attempt to use `instanceof`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to retrieve the run time class of the objects in your array to determine if the object is of type `Animal`. Just use `instanceof` the right way:

```
 public void notifyStateChange() {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (creatures[i] instanceof Animal) {
                System.out.println("Animal type here");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Alternately**, you can give the following a try. It is close to what you are trying. Just use `getSimpleName` instead of `getName`

```
public void notifyStateChange() {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Class c = creatures[i].getClass();
        if (c.getSimpleName().equals("Animal")) {
            System.out.println("Animal type here");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instanceOf doesn't work, but I think that may have to do with the fact that I am not building inside a package perhaps, but your alternative solution worked like a charm! thank you.

Comment: It brakes, when two classes have same name Animal and different packages. This is actually not good approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best appoach is to put action into `Animal` class itself or use wrappers in case of it is impossilbe. I give you and idea, because ther are many ways to implement it.
Your code should lookes like:

```
public void notifyStateChange() {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        creatures[i].doSmth();
    }
}
```

As alternative, you can put all `doSmth()` into `Enum` or in `Map` and choose correct instance somehere before in the code. Main problem with `if..else` is if you add new child of `Creature`, then you have to modify all these places.